cout is not outputting a hex value for 8 bit types, but 16 bits works fine
Something is amiss in my cout on my raspberry pi.  See example code below.  I need to print hex bytes, but they only show if they are ascii character values, ie. 0-9a-zA-Z.  It appears to be related to the data type.  It only does this on 8bit types, 16 bit types work fine.
uint8_t foo = 0x41;
uint16_t foo2 = 0x41;

std::cout << std::right << std::hex << std::uppercase << std::setfill('0');

cout << "foo1: 0x" << std::setw(2) << foo << endl;  // fail
cout << "foo2: 0x" << std::setw(2) << foo2 << endl; // works

Output:
0x0A
0x41
Where this is becoming a real problem for me is when the value is not ascii, ie. if I need to print 0x01, I get nothing.  Is there some other setting that I need to do?

All char based types, which includes uint8_t, will be output as characters. If you need it to be output as an integer, then you need to convert it to a non-character integer type, as in static_cast<uint16_t>(foo).

If you can use C++20 consider using std::format instead. std::cout << std::format("0x{:02x}", foo1);

Or std::print / std::println if you have C++23.
